# ReferenceError: [BABEL] src/app.js: Unknown option

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

The babel version I am using `6.24.1 (babel-core 6.26.3)`

I am trying to auto-generate `app.js` file inside scripts from source `app.js` by doing the following

`babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react`

I am getting the following error:

```
`ReferenceError: [BABEL] src/app.js: Unknown option: /home/my-pc/node_modules/react/index.js.Children. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`

For more detailed information on preset configuration, please see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins#pluginpresets-options. (While processing preset: "/home/my-pc/node_modules/react/index.js")
`
```

The **package.json** is as

```
{
  "name": "indecision-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Sid",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1"
  }
}
```